# How do I store cookie for subsequent connections with HttpClient

Tags: java, android

I have the following code that posts login details to a website. it works but how can I have the session cookie so I dont have to log in again for the other pages

edit: updated code

imports...

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    Button bLogin;
    EditText teUsername, tePassword;
    CheckBox chbRememberPass;

    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpResponse response;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        initialiseVars();
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkLoginDetails();
                test0();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialiseVars() {
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        teUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        tePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        chbRememberPass = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRememberPass);
    }

    private void checkLoginDetails() {


        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "mywebsite/login.php");
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "admin"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            Log.d("myapp", "works till here. 2");
            try {
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

                    Log.d("firstCon",responseBody);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void test0() {

        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(
                "https://mywebsite/userSettings.php");

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            //String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());         
            try {
                Log.d("secondCon", test());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("seconderror", e.toString());
            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new `DefaultHttpClient`, reuse it. Your cookies are stored in `DefaultHttpCilent`, so if you keep reusing the same instance, your cookies will be automatically handled for you.

Comment: I declared httpclient globally in the class but now when i try ti use it for a second time it says it is being used by the first method. when i do httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown() then the second method throws and error saying the manager is shut down. how do i realse it after one call and give it to another method?

Comment: @user521180: Step #1: Create the `DefaultHttpClient` in `onCreate()` of your activity. Step #2: Call `getConnectionManager().shutdown()` in `onDestroy()` of your activity. Step #3: If you plan on using this in multiple threads simultaneously, attach a `ThreadSafeClientConnectionManager` as documented on http://hc.apache.org. Step #4: Use the `DefaultHttpClient` as needed.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the code form my whole class. could you please show me how to do it so that `test0()` can retrieve data as well

Comment: @user521180: You already wrote the code "so that test0() can retrieve data as well".

Comment: But when `test0()` tries to retrieve `userSettings.php` it is met with the login page even though he first function successfully logged in. so I need to keep the session or cookie so that `test0()` can use it. that's where my problem is

Comment: @user521180: Since you are reusing the same `HttpClient` instance, it should handle that automatically. You can try to debug what is going on by such things as `getCookieStore()` on the `HttpClient` object, to see if your session cookie is being recorded based upon your initial request.